# How to pass a global variable value from a function in a js file to another function in a different file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

The file gallery.js basically creates a gallery of images inserted by the user.

In a file called gallery.js I have this function to know which image was selected by the user, that when he clicks it, creates a border around the image. This function will always be used first by the user.

```
var Nxml=0;
var NameFile =[]; // an array with all images names
var NameXml=[]; // array wth the name of the images selected
```

This function also in gallery.js retrieves the files inserted by the user with an html input button.

```
function handleFiles() {
"use strict";
var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
var fileList = inputElement.files;

for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){

 NameFile.push(fileList[i].name);

 /.../
 }
```

This function is called every time the user clicks an image presented in the gallery.

```
function imgClick(img) {

  if (img.className.indexOf('bordered') > -1) {
    img.className = img.className.replace('bordered', '').trim();
      Nxml=Nxml-1;
      alert(Nxml);
  // delete from the "NameXml" array the name of the image clicked

  } else {
    img.className += ' bordered';

   for( var i=0; i<NameFile.length;i++){

   if("imageID"+[i]===img.getAttribute("id")){ 
    Nxml=Nxml+1; 
    NameXml.push(NameFile[i]);

    alert(NameFile[i]);// name of the file selected
    alert(Nxml);// nr of clicks
}
   }
}
}
```

In a different file called XML.js I have a function that generates a xml file with the information posted on the form, and I want the number of xml generated to be the same as the var "Nxml" and name of each xml file to be the same as the image selected.

```
function download(frm){
    "use strict";
    alert(window.Nxml);
    alert(NameXml);

    for(var j=0; j<Nxml; j++){ 
    var N= NameXml[j];
    var data=fromToXml(frm);
  console.log(data);

  // aqui o nome do ficheiro
  downloadData("text/xml",data, N+".xml");  
    }

    }
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem/error? The second script should be able to access your `Nxml` variable (as long as the second script is declared after the first one). However, we don't know where `NameXml` is coming from

Comment: My problem is that every time i call the function download after select the images, the value of the array NameXml and the var Nxml comes empty. I already edit the code so that u can see. I also tried to merge the two js files but the same happens

Comment: @LuisLuisMaiaMaia try removing `var` from your initial assignment to `NameXml`

Comment: nope doesnt work either. I also i have tried creating a object with the property value, and then on the function "onclick" change the value of the property, but once i call the function "download" the object appers undifened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you decrement Nxml in imgClick(img) !! So it's always negative and the for loop in download  doesn't work.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Its never negative because the first time u click an image it creates the border and makes Nxml =1 , if the image already as a border makes Nxml-1 wich means Nxml=0. And the alert(Nxml) i have in the download function shows always 0.